How to find entity types in IQueryExpressionInterceptor?
How can I find all the entity types referenced by the Expression passed to IQueryExpressionInterceptor.QueryCompilationStarting? Where in the expression tree should I look for them?
I've tried a variety of queries and examined the Expression in the debugger. It seems that the entity types involved in the query always appear in the Type properties of the expression and its recursive Arguments, as themselves or as the type arguments to IQueryable or IIncludableQueryable. But I wonder if there are ways to construct a EF query where this would not be true.
Here are some of the query shapes I've tested. In every case, I see a series of nested MethodCallExpression (a LINQ type) enclosing an EntityQueryRootExpression (an EF type).
var first = await db.Foos.FirstAsync();

var name = await db.Foos.Select(f => f.Name).FirstAsync();

var foosWithBars = await db.Foos.Include(f => f.Bars).ToListAsync();

var bars = await db.Foos
    .Where(f => f.FooId == 1)
    .SelectMany(f => f.Bars)
    .ToListAsync();

var firstBar = await db.Foos
    .OrderBy(f => f.FooId)
    .Select(f => f.Bars.First())
    .FirstAsync();



I think, QueryRootExpression (or similar name) + analyse of all MemberExpression is enough. Anyway, what you are trying to solve?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm experimenting with query authorization by entity type. Most of the queries I've tried consist of nested MethodCallExpression2s around a EntityQueryRootExpression. Each MethodCallExpression2 also has a UnaryExpression, but that never seems to reference any entities.

EntityQueryRootExpression has property EntityType. Also analyse all MemberExpression, ignore methods and others. MemberExpression can be collection of child entities or navigation property to other entity, analayse it's Member property. So just create ExpressionVisitor which walk through these two expression types.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv What kind of LINQ would produce a MemberExpression? I'm not seeing those. Selecting an entity member is a MethodCallExpression. Includes are MethodCallExpressions. Taking the first entity from a DbSet is a MethodCallExpression.

x.Child, x.Child.Parent, etc is MemberExpression

@SvyatoslavDanyliv A bare expression like that is outside of the EF query. E.g., for db.Entities.FirstAsync().Child, only db.Entities.FirstAsync() is part of the query. Member access inside a Select is a MethodCallExpression. I added some other examples to my question.

If you create ExpressionVisitor, you will find a lot of MemberExpression in all of these trees. Just try. FirstAsync().Child is MemerExpression, db.Entities is EntityQueryRootExpression.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, FirstAsync().Child would be a MemberExpression... but as I said, it is not part of the expression passed to the interceptor. I've examined the trees in the debugger. There are no MemberExpressions to be found in any of them.

Select(f => f.Name) - f.Name, Include(f => f.Bars) - f.Bars, .OrderBy(f => f.FooId) - f.FooId, I can find them. Also install ReadableExpressions.Visualizers for better Expression visualisation. In (await FirstAsync()).Child, Child is not a part of Expression, it is C# compiled code. Object is retrieved from database and then property accessed in run-time.

Consider focusing only on QueryRootExpression and MemberExpression, as they contain sufficient information about which entities are involved in a LINQ query.
Below is a straightforward ExpressionVisitor implementation that gathers these entity types:
Usage:
var visitor = new EntitiesCollectorVisitor(db.Model);
visitor.Visit(queryExpression);

foreach (var entityType in visitor.Entities)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entityType.ClrType.Name);
}

Implementation:
public class EntitiesCollectorVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IModel _model;

    public HashSet<IEntityType> Entities { get; } = new();

    public EntitiesCollectorVisitor(IModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    void CollectTypes(Type type)
    {
        var entityType = _model.FindEntityType(type);
        if (entityType != null)
        {
            Entities.Add(entityType);
        }
        else if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            foreach (var genericArg in type.GenericTypeArguments)
                CollectTypes(genericArg);
        }
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        CollectTypes(node.Type);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitExtension(Expression node)
    {
        if (node is QueryRootExpression rootExpression)
        {
            CollectTypes(rootExpression.ElementType);
        }
        return base.VisitExtension(node);
    }
}


This handles every curveball I throw at it and does exactly what I asked: finds entity types in the query. There is a caveat for my intended use, though. If a navigation is configured with AutoInclude, entities of that type can be loaded without being part of a query.

@KevinKrumwiede, AutoInclude is different thing, in most used scenario, you can examine model with entities that were found by visitor, but in Select case, they can be ignored, which is also non-hundred percent solution. IOW, complex task.

What do you mean by Select case?

If you do not Select whole object, AutoInclude and Include is ignored by EF.
